# The socket server keep looping and only echo when the loop ends

Tags: php, sockets

I started server.php and client.php. After that, in client.php, I send some word or anything to server. The server keep looping without showing input (the message that client send). Once I type "q" in client.php (this to end the while loop in server.php) all the message that client sent before show up in server.php. The problem is I want the server to show the client message immediately after the client send to the server or show the client message real time. Is there anyway I can do that? Really appreciated if there is any solution on this. Thanks.

Here is server.php

```
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
 set_time_limit(0);
 ob_implicit_flush();
 $host = "127.0.0.1";
 $port = 25004;
 echo "Waiting for connections... \n";
 $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

 $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");

 $result = socket_listen($socket,0) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

 while(1){
  $spawn[++$i] = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
  echo "\n";
  $input = socket_read($spawn[$i], 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
  if($input== 'q'){break;}
  $input = trim($input);
  echo "Client Message : ".$input;
  $output = "aloha";
  socket_write($spawn[$i], $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
echo "\n";
 }
 socket_close($spawn);
 socket_close($socket);
?>
```

And here is my client.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CLient</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-3.3.7/docs/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="../bootstrap-3.3.7/docs/assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap-3.3.7/docs/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="client.php">
<p><h4><label>Type Your Message Here:<input name = "message" size = "25" maxlength = "30" required></label></h4></p>
<input type="submit" name="sendmsg" class="btn btn-primary" value="send message"/>
</form>

<?php
 $user="abc";
 if(empty($_POST)){ }

 elseif(isset($_POST['sendmsg'])) {
  $message =$_POST["message"];
  $host    = "127.0.0.1";
  $port    = 25004;

  echo "Message To server :".$message;

  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

  $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  

  socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");

  $result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
  echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;

  socket_close($socket);
 }  
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i think it is not about refreshing the page regularly because i tried with header("Refresh:0"); but the problem still there. The client message wont shown up unless i end the loop by send a 'q' from client to server.

Comment: do you need to send 'q' then only all the message send before can be display on server.php?

Comment: so your server.php page can display wht send from client without breaking the loop. I am using chrome but i have this problem. hrm... weird =(